# How to scroll to bottom scrollView when softkeyboard is open

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

I need to `ScrollView` scrolls to the bottom when the `EditText` request focus and soft keyboard is open.

Here is my xml code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/transfer_scroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue_500"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_transfer_senderLayout"
            style="@style/CardViewStyle.Transaction">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_selectRec"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_transfer_receiverLayout"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_below="@id/cv_transfer_senderLayout"
            style="@style/CardViewStyle.Transaction">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/transfer_layout_ll_receivers"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_transfer_setAmount"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_below="@id/cv_transfer_receiverLayout"
            style="@style/CardViewStyle.Transaction">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/transfer_layout_et_money"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:digits="0123456789"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_ed_ll_money"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxLength="7"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_400"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_summ" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is how I try to scroll to the bottom:

```
private void scrollDown(){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mScrollView.scrollTo(0, mScrollView.getBottom());
            Log.v("55555", "scrollDown");
        }
    }, 50);
}

mEditAmount.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        scrollDown();
    }
});
```

But this doesn't help. Keyboard is open and override rest of layout...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your problem is, is that the `ScrollView` can't reach the bottom or you don't want the soft keyboard cover your `ScrollView`?

###### For the first problem, you can try this in your handler:

```
mScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

Or you can change your code like this:

```
if (scroll == null || inner == null) {
    return;
}
 
int offset = inner.getMeasuredHeight() - scroll.getHeight();  

if (offset < 0) {
    offset = 0;
}
   
scroll.scrollTo(0, offset);
```

###### If you don't want a soft keyboard covering your layout, you can try these ways.

- First way: in `onCreate()`, before `setContentView` write code:

  ```
  getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
  ```
- Second way: in the `Activity` of `AndroidManifest.xml` add this line:

  ```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
  ```

Comment: what do you mean by `inner`?

Comment: public static void scrollToBottom(final View scroll, final View inner) {  
  
Handler mHandler = new Handler();  
  mHandler.post(new Runnable() {  
public void run() {  
if (scroll == null || inner == null) {  
 return;  
}  
 int offset = inner.getMeasuredHeight() - scroll.getHeight();  
if (offset < 0) {  offset = 0;  
}    
scroll.scrollTo(0, offset);  
 }  
});  
}

Comment: public static void scrollToBottom(final View scroll, final View inner)

Comment: View scroll represents the outer layer of the scrollview, and inner is in the inner layer of the scrollview. The contents of a scrollview are all in its inner view. Wish this can help you.